# Rails 3 nested attributes - association as choice

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, associations, nested-attributes

I am building a questionnaire for my website and I have models set up like so:

```
Question - has_many :answers
Answer - belongs_to :question
Response - belongs_to :answer, :user_application
UserApplication - has_many :responses
```

`Answers` are set answers, they could be Yes, No or a sentence, `Responses` are a nested resource of `UserApplication` so when I am hitting the new action in the `UserApplicationsController` I build responses, based on the number of questions, so I can use `f.fields_for` in the new form.  When it renders I want the nested response to have radio buttons which have the id for the answer.  So when the form is submitted the nested response receives the id for the selected answer.  I just can not figure out the best way to do this.  At the moment I am doing it like this:

UserApplicationController

```
  def new
    @user_application = UserApplication.new
    @questions = Question.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_application }
    end
  end
```

New Form

```
= form_for @user_application do |f|
  - @questions.each_with_index do |question, idx|
    = question.content
    .control-group
      .controls
        = select_tag "user_application[responses_attributes][#{idx}][answer_id]", options_for_select(question.answers.map {|u| [u.content,u.id]})
```

This feels a little hacky because when the user edits the application the select boxes for the previous answers are not selected.  I have tried to explain my problem as best as possible.  If anyone can understand what I am trying to do then any help would be appreciated!  If you need to know anything ask!

Thanks

Tony